# Encapsulate parts of my back-end application that are dynamically changed and added

Tags: python, node.js, integration

Hello Stack Overflow community!

### Scenario:

My application is a customer management platform fully based in NodeJS. It acts as a **middleware that integrates data from different systems**.

Customers can have some "services" activated and deactivated. **This application will control that they are entitled to perform such operations** when requested.

Making a change on those services will execute a script that **will contact external systems to query and update information, which eventually will return information whether it succeeded or not.** Normally these scripts are simple.

Until here everything is cool. We could simply integrate the service scripting for each service into the main application and that's all, right?

What I haven't said yet is: there will be a **big number of different services** (potentially we could end up having hundreds), and **they will be changed often**, for example, if a promotion is launched.

### The challenge:

We can't be releasing a new version of the customer management application just to launch a new service; there is little encapsulation so things may break; performance of those new scripts may affect the main application; need to restart the main application to apply changes, etc.

**I want to be able to create and modify a big number of these services at any time in a "Plug&Play" fashion**, integrating this into the main application is not a really beautiful solution.

### The question:

How would you encapsulate these many scripts that can be dynamically changed at any time apart from the main application?

I was thinking about programming those services as Python scripts that are called from the main application when required. Python is simple and multi-platform and runs separately. **Is this a good approach?** Please don't hesitate to tell me how horrible the idea is if by any chance it was!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's been a long time without an answer, so I am giving my conclusion:

After speaking with two back-end programming engineers, they approved my solution, which is to load (using `require`) the JavaScript files for each "add-on" piece (referred as "component" in the code) and then execute it and lastly flush the cache.

This solution allows to edit the files on the go without restarting the program and allows everything to stay organized in one single file if desired.

```
// Component script load part:
let componentScriptPath = '../custom_component_scripts/' + component_id;
let componentScript;
try {
    componentScript = require(componentScriptPath);
} catch(error) {
    console.error('critical', 'Failed to read or find scripts for component "' + component_id + '". Error: ' + error);
    delete require.cache[require.resolve(componentScriptPath)];
    console.log('Flushed script cache for "' + component_id + '"');
    throw error;
}

// Component script execution part:
try {
    await componentScript.actions[operation](subscription_id, parameters)
    console.log('Component script for "' + component_id + '" reported success');
} catch(error) {
    console.error('Component script for "' + component_id + '" reported failure');
    throw error;
} finally {
    delete require.cache[require.resolve(componentScriptPath)];
    console.log('Flushed script cache for "' + component_id + '"');
}
```